# When I try to use .fit on my decision tree classifier it gives an error in notebook

Tags: python

This is my code.
I use jupyter notebook trying to start machine learning after learning the basics so if you have other tips much appreciated.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
music_data = pd.read_csv('music.csv')
X = music_data.drop(columns = ['genre'])
y = music_data['genre']

model = DecisionTreeClassifier
model.fit(X,y)
music_data
```

and I get an error "model.fit is missing the positional argument y".

Comment: Why are you writing `model = DecisionTreeClassifier` instead of `model = DecisionTreeClassifier()`? You want `model` to be an *instance* of the `DecisionTreeClassifier` class, not an alias for the `DecisionTreeClassifier` class itself, right?

Comment: yes sorry im just really new

Comment: Yea sorry I noticed I forgot () stupid me

Comment: Does your code work if you add the `()`?